# menu of li:nth-child() color formatting

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a menu containing of ul li items. I have five items, using flexbox to align them with the last item using `margin-left:auto;` to push it to the right.

I am also using transform: skewX(45deg) to create arrows for each `li::before` and `li::after` and I have a starting background-color. The arrow border is set to yellow.

My problem is that I would like to individually set the color for each li item, except the last li.

So, I would like to use li:nt-child property and set the background color and also take into account for before and after values.

I am guessing I need also to use the z-index maybe so the previous before and after color values are handled in a proper way.

This is my html code:

```
<nav class="flex-nav" id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="./index.pug">Home page</a></li>
      <li><a href="./test.pug">Test page</a></li>
      <li><a href="./test.pug">Link1</a></li>
      <li><a href="./test.pug">Link2</a></li>
      <li><a href="./test.pug">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

And this is my css:

```
.flex-nav ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.flex-nav ul li {
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    opacity: 1.0;
    transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 26px;
    margin: 0 9px 0 -10px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

ul li::before,
ul li::after {
    border-right: 4px solid yellow;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: skewX(45deg);
    background-color: #b0e0e6;
}




ul li::after {
    bottom: 0;
    top: auto;
    transform: skewX(-45deg);
}

ul li:last-of-type::before,
ul li:last-of-type::after {
    display: none;
}

ul li a {
    font: bold 18px Sans-Serif;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    text-decoration: none;

}

ul>li:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
}

ul:hover>li:not(:hover) {
    opacity: 0.5;
}


.flex-nav ul li:last-child {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: So what is your actual question?

Comment: My aciua?? Sorry, I don't follow you.

Comment: Refresh page and read again...

Comment: I would like to set the individual li items with a different colors.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? ... and what is not working? ... or are you asking someone here to write up some code for you?

Comment: No!! I am trying to learn css. I have tried with li:nth-child to set different colors, but it the new color makes the arrow vanish. I am not sure, but I think I need to tinker with z-index maybe and also test each nth-child before and after property, but I am not sure.

Comment: None of what you now wrote is present in the question, so not easy for us to help. Provide a [mcve] of what you have so we can see what it is that doesn't work.

Comment: thanks for you input, I provided the complete code in my question. But @Hassan showed me what was missing in my code, and its working, and I learned what was missing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191071/discussion-between-user2371684-and-lgson).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below CSS for change the background color for first, second and third items. Thanks

```css
.flex-nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.flex-nav ul li {
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 1.0;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 26px;
  margin: 0 9px 0 -10px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.flex-nav li:before,
.flex-nav li:after {
  border-right: 4px solid yellow;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: skewX(45deg);
}

.flex-nav li:first-child::before,
.flex-nav li:first-child::after {
  background-color: red;
}

.flex-nav li:nth-child(2)::before,
.flex-nav li:nth-child(2)::after {
  background-color: green;
}

.flex-nav li:nth-child(3)::before,
.flex-nav li:nth-child(3)::after {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<nav class="flex-nav" id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="./index.pug">Home page</a></li>
      <li><a href="./test.pug">Test page</a></li>
      <li><a href="./test.pug">Link1</a></li>
      <li><a href="./test.pug">Link2</a></li>
      <li><a href="./test.pug">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Please in the future use the code snippet  `<>`  provided by StackOverflow to create your answers.

Comment: thanks again, I tried to mark it as correct yesterday, but it didn't let me, not enough time had passed :) I have another question regarding nth:child and pseudo elements, can I ask you directly?

Comment: @hassan siddiqui I was looking for a chat function, is there a way to connect to you directly?

Comment: Can we do the chat again if you are online? :)